# How do I pass arguments to a command inside a PowerShell script?

Tags: java, powershell

I want to execute the Java command: `java -jar cli.jar <arg> <arg>` from inside a PowerShell script. How do I pass the command line arguments passed to the PowerShell script to the Java command inside the script?

Comment: What is your question? How to write a powershell script that calls a java program? Or how that java program can react to the arguments provided to it?

Comment: I think the question is how to convey the arguments passed by the caller of the script to the java program to be executed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to pass commandline arguments to powershell script, you can use `$args` (this inbuilt variable will contain the arguments passed in the commandline)

```
foreach ($arg in $args) {
    "cli argument " + $arg
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you call your program like you did your application would receive three parameters, namely:

- dir
- -t
- i:\app

When you write your application you would normally write a main method that takes an arg array like this:

```
public static void main (String[] args)
{
   // Code
}
```

To answer your question, the args array would now contain your three parameters. So if you would change your main method to:

```
public static void main (String[] args)
{
   for (String arg : args) System.out.println(arg);
}
```

You would see your input parameters on the command line.

Answer (score 1):

#### Solution 1

Your script ps1

```
    param (
        [string[]]$ListParam
    )

    [string[]]$ListParamAll= "-jar", "cli.jar"
    $ListParamAll+=$ListParam

    start-process  "java"  -ArgumentList $ListParamAll
```

How to call this script:

```
    cli.ps1 -ListParam dir,-t,i:\app
```